Uploading an image from Google Drive to Google Earth Engine as a GEE Asset
I have a .tif file that I would like to upload to GEE as a Google Earth Engine asset. Obviously this can be done manually through the GEE interface. But I was wondering how this can be done from a Python/Google Colab environment. I am working with the geemap python package.
Here is my code (output.tif is a file that is in my current directory).
img = 'output.tif'
imgcasted = ee.Image(img)

assetId = 'projects/servir-sco-assets/assets/flood_intercomparison/pk_case_study/mcdwd/mcdwdtest'

geemap.ee_export_image_to_asset(
    imgcasted, description='mcdwdtest', assetId=assetId, scale=30
)

When I run the code, I get the below EEException: "Image.load: Image asset 'output.tif' not found (does not exist or caller does not have access)."
I assume this is because i cannot cast an image that is in my Google Drive to an Earth Engine image.
Is there anyway this can be done other than manually uploading images on the interface or uploading them to Google Cloud storage, then using the command line interface to upload them?

If you haven't checked the video: https://youtu.be/CKKa9-zU51Q?si=ujLBxPyT-qlTsag6
May be that is helpful.
